# How to use new Hadoop parquet magic commiter to custom S3 server with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have spark 2.4.0 and Hadoop 3.1.1. According to [Hadoop Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committer_architecture.html), to use the new Magic committer that allow write of parquet files to S3 consistently, I've setup those values in `conf/spark-default.conf`:

```
spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass       com.hortonworks.spark.cloud.commit.PathOutputCommitProtocol
spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.BindingPathOutputCommitter
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a    org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name          magic
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled true
```

When using this configuration I end up with the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hortonworks.spark.cloud.commit.PathOutputCommitProtocol
```

My question is double, first do I properly understand that Hadoop 3.1.1 allow write of parquet file to S3 consistently ?
Second, if I did understand well, how to use the new committer properly from Spark ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
OK, I've two intances of server one being a bit old now, I've attempted to use last version of minio with those parameters:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access","true")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer","bytebuffer")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access","true")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.multipart.size","128M")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload.active.blocks","4")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.committer.name","partitioned")
```

I'm able to write so far without trouble.
However my swift server which is a bit older with this config:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.signing-algorithm","S3SignerType")
```

seems to not support properly the partionner.

Regarding "Hadoop S3guard":
It is not possible currently, Hadoop S3guard that keep metadata of the S3 files must be enable in Hadoop. The S3guard though rely on DynamoDB a proprietary Amazon service.
There's no alternative now like a sqlite file or other DB system to store the metadata.
So if you're using S3 with `minio` or any other S3 implementation, you're missing DynamoDB.
This article explains nicely [how works S3guard](https://hortonworks.com/blog/s3guard-amazon-s3-consistency/)

Comment: Sorry, missed this. If your object store is has list consistency then you don't need s3guard. Use the staging committer and leave it generating unique UUIDs on every file (avoid problem of write-after-write consistency). As for the signing type -that should not matter. File a JIRA on issues.apache.org /hadoop, include any stack traces

Answer (score 1):

Kiwy: that's my code: I can help you with this. Some of the classes haven't got into the ASF spark releases, but you'll find the in the Hadoop JARs, and I could have a go at building the ASF release with the relevant dependencies in (I could put them in downstream; they used to be there)

You do not need S3Guard turned on to use the "staging committer"; it's only the "magic" variant which needs consistent object store listings during the commit phase.

Comment: I won't be able to use Magic Commiter I'm trying to use `  fs.s3a.committer.name=partitioned` and `fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode=fail` So far it's is OK. replace mode would consistently throw a 403 error I suspect my instance of Swift is not to be relied on. I should try with a recent minio server to confirm how consistent the error is. You've been of great help Steve, Thank you a lot.

Comment: Not tested with either. If it doesn't work, file a bug on Apache jira, component "fs/s3", link to [S3A features for Hadoop 3.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15620)

Comment: So far my attempts from a s3 500GB csv to s3 parquet in 3393 pieces failed with this message: filecsv.write.parquet("s3a://bucket/file.parquet")
2018-11-21 12:47:36 ERROR FileFormatWriter:91 - Aborting job 594be6.
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: delete on s3a://bucket/file.parquet/_temporary: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: txa745d7; S3 Extended Request ID: null)

Comment: I confirm you that older swift release might not support the new partitionner. thank you for you amazing work.

Answer (score 0):

All the new committers config documentation I've read up to date, is missing one fundamental fact:

### spark 2.x.x does not have needed support classes to make new S3a committers to function.

They promise those [cloud integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11) libs will be bundled with spark 3.0.0, but for now you have to add libraries yourself.

Under the [cloud integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11) maven repos there are multiple distributions supporting the committers, I found [one working with directory committer](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/org/apache/spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11/2.4.0.7.0.3.0-79/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.4.0.7.0.3.0-79.jar) but not the magic.

In general the directory committer is the recommended over magic as it has been well tested and tried. It requires shared filesystem (magic committer does not require one, but needs s3guard) such as HDFS or NFS (we use AWS EFS) to coordinate spark worker writes to S3.

Comment: if the spark binding works with the directory committers; it will work with the magic one...all it does is fix up spark and parquet committers to delegate to the plugin point in the hadoop module which allows each FS to choose a committer...