# Enabling the Directory Committer in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to use S3A Partitioned(or Directory as I just need to confirm if committer is working as expected) committer with Spark. I am following this [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/bk_cloud-data-access/content/ch03s08s05.html) based on which it should be pretty simple however I am running into new issues while resolving previous one

Code used for testing is (inside `spark-shell`):

```scala
val sourceDF = spark.range(0, 10000)
val datasets = "s3a://bucket-name/test"
sourceDF.write.format("orc").save(datasets + "orc")
```

`spark-defaults.conf` is:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name directory

spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol

spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter


Error 1:
scala> sourceDF.write.format("orc").save(datasets + "orc")
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/PathOutputCommitter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol$.instantiate(FileCommitProtocol.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org .apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.PathOutputCommitter
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 81 more
```

Then I copied spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.3.1.3.0.2.0-50.jar from this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11/2.3.1.3.0.2.0-50) into spark/jars folder

This resolved the previous ``NoClassDefFoundError` but produced new class def error which is:

Error 2:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/PathOutputCommitter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol$.instantiate(FileCommitProtocol.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
....
```

Full stacktrace can be pasted if needed

After this, I copied hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.1.1.jar into spark/jars folder and ran the test code in spark-shell again. This time I got below error:

**After this, I am stuck.**

Error 3 (and final error where I am stuck):

```
scala> sourceDF.write.format("orc").save(datasets + "orc")
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol.<init>(PathOutputCommitProtocol.scala:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol$.instantiate(FileCommitProtocol.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
... 48 elided
```

This looks like incorrect jar issue but I am not able to find the correct one. 
This question is similar to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388976/how-to-use-new-hadoop-parquet-magic-commiter-to-custom-s3-server-with-spark?answertab=active#tab-top) but could not find relevant answer hence posting again.

Answer (score 2):

All the new committers config documentation I've read up to date, is missing one fundamental fact:

### spark 2.x.x does not have needed support classes to make new S3a committers to function.

They promise those [cloud integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11) libs will be bundled with spark 3.0.0, but for now you have to add libraries yourself.

Under the [cloud integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11) maven repos there are multiple distributions supporting the committers, I found [one working with the directory committer](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/org/apache/spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11/2.4.0.7.0.3.0-79/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.4.0.7.0.3.0-79.jar)

Please also remember that the directory committer requires shared filesystem such as HDFS or NFS (we use AWS EFS) to coordinate spark worker writes to S3.

If it is not set properly, the resulting S3 write location will contain empty folder with single _SUCCESS file in it.

If you set your committer properly, the _SUCCESS file will contain the JSON status of the write. If it is empty (zero length), means you still use the default spark s3 committer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work. Issue was with my spark version. I was using spark 2.2.1 version whereas atleast spark 2.3.1 is needed.
Last error mentioned in the question was pointing to wrong constructor. After digging a little bit, I found out that spark-core_2.11-2.2.1.jar was using two parameter constructor where as spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.3.1.3.0.2.0-50.jar was expecting 3 parameter constructor which came only in spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar version. After version bump and with few tweaks, I was able to test this.

Run this command to see the issue:

javap -classpath spark-core_2.11-2.2.1.jar  org/apache/spark/internal/io/HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol

javap -classpath spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar  org/apache/spark/internal/io/HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol

Just to let you know, I downloaded spark 2.3.1 without pre-built hadoop version, then configured it with hadoop 3.1.0 jars and was able to make it work.