# UnsatisfiedLinkError while writing to S3 using Staging S3A Committer on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write Parquet data to AWS S3 directory with Apache Spark. I use my local machine on Windows 10 without having Spark and Hadoop installed, but rather added them as SBT dependency (Hadoop 3.2.1, Spark 2.4.5). My SBT is below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hadoop-cloud" % "2.3.2.3.1.0.6-1",

  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.2.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.2.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.2.1",

  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-bundle" % "1.11.704"
)

dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.11.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.11.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.11.0"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache" at "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2",
  "hortonworks" at "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/",
)
```

I use S3A Staging Directory Committer as described in [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#Using_the_Directory_and_Partitioned_Staging_Committers) and [Cloudera](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/enabling-directory-committer-spark.html) documentation. I'm also aware of these two questions on StackOverflow and used them for proper configuration:

- [Apache Spark + Parquet not Respecting Configuration to use “Partitioned” Staging S3A Committer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60955453/apache-spark-parquet-not-respecting-configuration-to-use-partitioned-staging)
- [How To Get Local Spark on AWS to Write to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495909/how-to-get-local-spark-on-aws-to-write-to-s3)

I have added all required (as of my understanging) configurations including latest two specific for Parquet:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("test-run-s3a-commiters")
      .master("local[*]")

      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum", "100")

      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "directory")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled", "false")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode", "append")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.unique-filenames", "true")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.abort.pending.uploads", "true")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "tmp/")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.tmp.path", "hdfs_tmp/")
      .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
      .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory")

      .config("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol")
      .config("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter")
      .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("info")
```

From the logs I can see that *StagingCommitter* is actually applied (also I can see intermediate data in my local filesystem under specified paths and no *_temporary* directory in S3 during execution like it would be with default *FileOutputCommitter*).

Then I'm running simple code to write test data to S3 bucket:

```
import spark.implicits._

val sourceDF = spark
  .range(0, 10000)
  .map(id => {
    Thread.sleep(10)
    id
  })

sourceDF
  .write
  .format("parquet")
  .save("s3a://my/test/bucket/")
```

(I use `Thread.sleep` to simulate some processing and have little time to check the intermediate content of my local temp directory and S3 bucket)

However, I get an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat` error during commit task attempt.
Below is the piece of logs (reduced to 1 executor) and error stack trace.

```
20/05/09 15:13:18 INFO InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 15000
20/05/09 15:13:18 INFO StagingCommitter: Starting: Task committer attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: needsTaskCommit() Task attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0
20/05/09 15:13:18 INFO StagingCommitter: Task committer attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: needsTaskCommit() Task attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: duration 0:00.005s
20/05/09 15:13:18 INFO StagingCommitter: Starting: Task committer attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: commit task attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0
20/05/09 15:13:18 INFO StagingCommitter: Task committer attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: commit task attempt_20200509151301_0000_m_000000_0: duration 0:00.019s
20/05/09 15:13:18 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2091)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$5.hasNext(FileSystem.java:2190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.applyLocatedFiles(S3AUtils.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.flatmapLocatedFiles(S3AUtils.java:1333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.listAndFilter(S3AUtils.java:1350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.staging.StagingCommitter.getTaskOutput(StagingCommitter.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.staging.StagingCommitter.commitTask(StagingCommitter.java:641)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol.commitTask(PathOutputCommitProtocol.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/05/09 15:13:18 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
```

According to my current understanding, the configuration is correct. Probably, the error is caused by some version incompatibilities or my local environment settings.

Provided code works as expected for ORC and CSV without any error, but not for Parquet.

Please, suggest what could cause the error and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For everyone who comes here, I found the solution. As expected, the problem is not related to S3A output committers or library dependencies.

The UnsatisfiedLinkError exception on Java native method raised because of version incompatibility between Hadoop version in SBT dependencies and winutils.exe (HDFS wrapper) on my Windows machine.

I've downloaded corresponding version from [cdarlint/winutils](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) and it all worked. LOL

Answer (score 1):

this is related to the installation not having the native libs to support the file:// URL, and s3a using that for buffering writes.

you can switch to using memory for buffering -just make sure that you are uploading to s3 as fast as you generate data. there are some options covered in the s3a docs to help manage that by limiting the #of active blocks a single output stream can queue for uploading in parallel.

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer</name>
    <value>bytebuffer</value>
  </property>
```