# Pyspark throwing error while trying to read parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am a newbie in pyspark, While trying to read parquet file through pyspark I get the below error. I have tried various things like reinstallation of jre and jdk, updating environment variables. Matching winutils.exe but nothing seems to work.

Error: **

```
An error occurred while calling o60.load.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**

Edit - code is quite simple:-

```
python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

path = "C:\\ProgramData\\MyData"

df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header",True).load(str(path))
```

I am using spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2. Python version is 3.10.

Solution:- Copy winutils from [link](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) and try one by one version and check which version is working. Ideally the version matching with Pyspark version should work but different version worked in my case.

Please help out if you get any clue.

Comment: Can you share your code for a reproducible example along with your file source and spark environment details ?

Comment: @glory9211: I have edited my question to give details. As for sample parquet is concerned I am not not able to read any parquet file although pyspark is able to read json. Pandas is able to load the same parquet file just fine.

Comment: can you try reading with this ```spark.read.parquet(path)``` also check if spark has parquet jar files. If no success then create a df in spark and try to save it in parquet instead of reading one. This will help in debugging

Comment: it says `UnsatisfiedLinkError` that means there are incompatible packages in your environment.   looks like you are using windows, try checking out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696990/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-apache-spark-when-writing-parquet-to-aws-s3-using-stagin

Comment: Thanks for your Reponses. Found the the issue with winutils version. I copied all the winutils from [link](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) and tried one by one. It worked with one version. Ideally it should not be like this but it worked somehow.