# PySpark: Unable to save RDD into CSV file

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file like below.

| id | 100-32.12 | 101-33.22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23421.2341 | 4398012.4629 |
| 1235 | 67892.5643 | 9875681.3829 |

I have first had my file (myFile.csv) into a RDD:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
my_rdd = sc.textFile('file:///D:/PyPractice/testData/myFile.csv')
```

Later I tried saving the same data into a new file:

```
my_rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file:///D:/PyPractice/sameData.csv")
```

This is giving me error as below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-865a9df3b103> in <module>
      1 my_rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('file:///D:/PyPractice/sameData.csv')

C:\PySpark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\rdd.py in saveAsTextFile(self, path, compressionCodecClass)
   2203             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
   2204         else:
-> 2205             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
   2206 
   2207     # Pair functions

C:\PySpark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

C:\PySpark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1089)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1062)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1009)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1599)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1585)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1585)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:564)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitJob(OutputCommitter.java:291)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$3(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
    ... 51 more
```

Please help me understand what is the mistake I'm doing here and help me to get a solution for this.

Comment: please if check your hadoop dll files and winutils installation is correct and accessible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsatisfiedLinkError while writing to S3 using Staging S3A Committer on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696990/unsatisfiedlinkerror-while-writing-to-s3-using-staging-s3a-committer-on-windows)

Comment: I have replaced latest winutils.exe file as well.
Got the file from: https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils
But still facing the issue

Comment: the winutils should match the hadoop version. if not, install the correct version. e.g., if you've installed hadoop 2.x.y, your winutils should match 2.x.y

Comment: I have installed Spark 3.3.1 version and I have placed the same version of winutils in bin folder.
Not sure what's the issue. Facing the issue still.

Comment: Anyone can help me on this please?